# ADF data flow not giving cosmos query results with the parameters

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

**Disclaimer : I am very new to Azure Development**

In Azure Data factory Dataflow in source option when I have hardcoded the date string and  used below query it gives the results as expected for cosmos DB.

```
“select c.column1,c.column2 from c where c.time_stamp >= '2010-01-01T20:28:45Z' and c.time_stamp <= '2020-09-11T20:28:45Z'”
```

When I have passed the parameters which I have mapped in pipeline and use the query with parameters I am not getting any result.

```
"oldwatermark": "'2010-01-01T20:28:45Z'",
"newwatermark": "'2020-09-11T20:28:45Z'"


“select c.column1,c.column2 from c where c.time_stamp >= ‘$oldwatermark’ and c.time_stamp <= ‘$oldwatermark’”
```

Could you please suggest what am I doing wrong here as my parameter values and hardcoded values are same.

Comment: Can you try `concat('select c.column1,c.column2 from c where c.time_stamp >= ',$oldwatermark,'and c.time_stamp <= ',$oldwatermark)` or only `select c.column1,c.column2 from c where c.time_stamp >= $oldwatermark and c.time_stamp <= $oldwatermark`?

Comment: Hi @Amit Anand, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonYue Sorry for the late response. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from your worked statements, your query should be:

```
select c.column1,c.column2 from c where c.time_stamp >= $oldwatermark and c.time_stamp <= $newwatermark
```

not `where c.time_stamp >= $oldwatermark and c.time_stamp <= $oldwatermark`.

**Please don't use the quotes for the parameter in the query**.

Please try this query:

```
concat('select c.column1,c.column2 from c where c.time_stamp >= ',$oldwatermark,'and c.time_stamp <= ',$newwatermark)
```

[image]

[image]